# What does .* (dot star) mean in SQL?

Tags: sql

What does the `.*` mean in SQL?

I saw it in this query:

```
SELECT 
  socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen.*,
  socialmedia_zielgruppen.ziel_benutzer,
  socialmedia_zielgruppen.ziel_benutzergruppe,
  socialmedia_zielgruppen.ziel_dashboardgruppe
FROM 
  socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen 
  INNER JOIN socialmedia_zielgruppen 
    ON socialmedia_zielgruppen.socialmedia_stunden_ID = socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen.ID
```

Comment: `*` means select all columns

Comment: .* and the dot ?

Comment: can you add the rest of the sql statement also....it becomes more clear what you are trying to do...

Comment: $sql  = "SELECT  socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen.*,socialmedia_zielgruppen.ziel_benutzer,socialmedia_zielgruppen.ziel_benutzergruppe,socialmedia_zielgruppen.ziel_dashboardgruppe    FROM socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen 
                 inner join socialmedia_zielgruppen 
         on  socialmedia_zielgruppen.socialmedia_stunden_ID=socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen.ID";

Comment: This is really stuff you should be learning from a beginner tutorial, rather than asking us. If you check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html, you’ll see that this is the syntax using table name and column name as a combined identifier for a column, only the column name part here is `*` to select _all_ columns of that table.

Comment: I didn't ask you specifically that first and second I'm asking about the dot .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*` means "all columns".

Combined with the `.` and the prefix it means "all columns from the table/alias named".

So in your case

```
SELECT socialmedia_kat_stundenvorlagen.*
```

means "select all columns from the socialmeda_kat_stundenvorlagen table". You can do that so you get only the specific columns from that table, not all the columns from all the joined tables as well.